# Migration .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1- LINQ LEFT JOIN - Calling Take() on DefaultIfEmpty does not translate to server side SQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have following code in .NET CORE 2.2.After migrating entire project to .net core 3.1, it does not works in .NET 3.1. According to [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) it says `DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)` will not translate to SQL.

```
from students in Students.Where(e => e.StudentType == studentType)
join courseDetails in Course.Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
on students.CourseId equals courseDetails.Id into studentCourse
from courseDetails in studentCourse.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)
select new { students, courseDetails };
```

When I ran above LINQ statement I got following error.

> 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate
> either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
> information.",

PS: As per the requirement I must use `Take(1)`.
Because for each record in left side table right side can have multiple
records.from that we will take only 1 record.

can anyone  share suggestion to do it without breaking the LINQ Query

Comment: Is it possible that you could just leave out `DefaultIfEmpty()`, and just take 1? Or use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `DefaultIfEmpty()` and `Take(1)`

Comment: Note that EF Core 2.x versions automatically performed client side evaluation for non-translatable calls (i.e. fetch everything and manage it client side).

Comment: Have you tried removing `Take(1)` and something like `select new { students, courseDetail = courseDetails.FirstOrDefault() };`?

Comment: If you set your nav properties up correctly, this query would more simply be something like `context.StudentCourses.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.Student.StudentType == studentType && sc.Course.IsActive)`

Comment: @CaiusJard , this is not traditional student, course scenario, I have staged those names. only requirement performing leftjoin with Take(1)  => DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)

Comment: @GuruStron  I have to do the "Take(1)" operation while joining. Because right side table will have multiple rows , from that we select only 1.

Comment: @AslamJiffry have you checked if my suggestion works and generated SQL? Don't assume how the query will be translated - check it.

Comment: @GuruStron  yes I have.  "courseDetails" is an instance . not a list. so I am unable to perform "FirstOrDefault()" . when I tried to do that intellisense shows object properties

Comment: @AslamJiffry do you have a relation set up between `Students` and `Course` tables on EF Core model level?

Comment: @GuruStron Here I have used staged name. for a reason I couldn't use the real names. for 1 student record we can have multiple course records or no records. if there are multiple records from that we only take 1 record. for that we use "Take(1)" with "DefaultIfEmpty". Obviously "DefaultIfEmpty" for performing leftjoin. hope you understand. --  Names are not real. But logic is where I have issue when executing LINQ.

Comment: If you set your nav properties up correctly, EFC will perform left joins for you; `context.Students.Include(s => s.Courses)` if EF can see Student:Course is 1:0..M

Answer (score 2):

I never do that in that way, I every time use `First OR Default`

```
from students in Students.Where(e => e.StudentType == studentType)
join courseDetails in Course.Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
on students.CourseId equals courseDetails.Id into studentCourse
from courseDetails in studentCourse.FirstOrDefault()
select new { students, courseDetails };
```

Comment: This should be left join. If we remove DefaultIFEmpty() , unable to perform leftjoin. or is it ?

Comment: @AslamJiffry Well, I never do the way you do it, but I'm 100% sure that there is the same. You are using it over the "cross table", i mean studentCourse. The conditions will apply over studentCourse.

Comment: It gave me following error. exactly on 'studentCourse.FirstOrDefault()'                          
An expression of type 'Course' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 
'IQueryable<<anonymous type: Students students, IEnumerable<courseDetails> studentCourse>>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

Comment: @AslamJiffry what about separate the logic and do the null checks and removings over the already result?

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```cs
var query = from students in Students.AsQueryable().Where(e => e.StudentType == studentType)
    from courseDetails in Course.AsQueryable()
        .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
        .Where(cd => cd.Id == students.CourseId)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()        
    select new { students, courseDetails };
```

I don't have 3.1 installed on my machine, but 5.0 seems to translate it correctly.

Comment: with this query this " .Where(cd => cd.Id == students.CourseId)" line will give error if there are no matching records, since this is LeftJoin. Further it gave me error when using two from clauses one after another. I am using visual studion 2019. .net core 3.1

Comment: @AslamJiffry again - I don't have 3.1 installed, but tor 5.0 it translates into left join.

Comment: I like the way to think this